# How to pop the NavigationStack to root without path? or if not possible, how to avoid reinitializing ViewModel?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to pop the NavigationStack to root.

`NavigationStack(path:)` and `.navigationDestination(for:,destination:)` with `path = .init()` allows me to pop to root view.

The problem with using `NavigationStack(path:)` and `.navigationDestination(for:,destination:)`:

1. the destination will be initialized twice.
2. the `@StateObject` inside the destination will be initialized twice.

My expected result: View can be initialized once to many times. The ViewModel should only be initialized when the View will appear.

My actual result: View can be initialized once to many times. The ViewModel gets initialized twice. Worse, when I leave the View, only 1 ViewModel gets deinit. I suspect this will cause memory leak.

`NavigationLink(destination:,label:)` does not have the bug suffered by the previous method.

1. the destination will be initialized once.
2. the `@StateObject` will not be initialized unless I click the NavigationLink.

The problem with using `NavigationLink(destination:,label:)`:

1. Unable to pop to root view.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  NavigationStackExample
//
//  Created by Jason Rich Darmawan Onggo Putra on 29/07/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Station {
    let name: String
}

class SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var departure: Station?
    @Published var arrival: Station?
    @Published var departureSelected: Bool
    var arrivalSelected: Bool {
        get {
            !departureSelected
        }
        set {
            departureSelected = !newValue
        }
    }
    
    init(departure: Station? = nil, arrival: Station? = nil, departureSelected: Bool = false) {
        self.departure = departure
        self.arrival = arrival
        self.departureSelected = departureSelected
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

enum SelectDepartureArrivalViewRoute { case CommutingView }

struct SelectDepartureArrivalView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel = SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SelectDepartureArrivalView")
            Text("Departure \(viewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Text("Arrival \(viewModel.arrival?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                viewModel.departure = Station(name: "Lebak Bulus Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set departure")
            }
            Button {
                viewModel.arrival = Station(name: "Fatmawati Indomaret Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set arrival")
            }
            
            Text("path").font(.largeTitle)
            Button {
                coordinator.path.append(SelectDepartureArrivalViewRoute.CommutingView)
            } label: {
                Text("Simulating commuting with path")
            }
            
//            Text("NavigationLink").font(.largeTitle)
//            NavigationLink {
//                CommutingView(selectDepartureViewModel: viewModel)
//            } label: {
//                Text("Simulate commuting with NavigationLink")
//            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
        .navigationDestination(for: SelectDepartureArrivalViewRoute.self, destination: { _ in
            CommutingView(selectDepartureViewModel: viewModel)
        })
    }
}

class CommutingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentStation: Station?
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

enum CommutingViewRoute { case ArrivedView }

struct CommutingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    @ObservedObject var selectDepartureViewModel: SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: CommutingViewModel = CommutingViewModel()
    
    init(selectDepartureViewModel: SelectDepartureArrivalViewModel) {
        self.selectDepartureViewModel = selectDepartureViewModel
        
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("CommutingView")
            Text("Departure \(selectDepartureViewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Text("Arrival \(selectDepartureViewModel.arrival?.name ?? "")")
            Text("Current Station \(viewModel.currentStation?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                viewModel.currentStation = Station(name: "Fatmawati Indomaret Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set current station")
            }
            
            Text("path").font(.largeTitle)
            Button {
                coordinator.path.append(CommutingViewRoute.ArrivedView)
            } label: {
                Text("Simulate arrival with path")
            }
            
//            Text("NavigationLink").font(.largeTitle)
//            NavigationLink {
//                ArrivedView(commutingViewModel: viewModel)
//            } label: {
//                Text("Simulate arrival with NavigationLink")
//            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
        .navigationDestination(for: CommutingViewRoute.self, destination: { _ in
            ArrivedView(commutingViewModel: viewModel)
        })
    }
}

class ArrivedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

struct ArrivedView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    @ObservedObject var commutingViewModel: CommutingViewModel
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ArrivedViewModel = ArrivedViewModel()
    
    init(commutingViewModel: CommutingViewModel) {
        self.commutingViewModel = commutingViewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ArrivedView")
            Text("Current station \(commutingViewModel.currentStation?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                coordinator.path = .init()
            } label: {
                Text("Simulate exit")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
    }
}

class ScheduleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)") }
}

struct ScheduleView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ScheduleViewModel = ScheduleViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ScheduleView")
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
    }
}

class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var step = 0
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
}

enum ContentViewRoute {
    // Feature 1
    case SelectDepartureArrivalView
    
    // Feature 2
    case ScheduleView
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
            VStack {
                Text("path").font(.largeTitle)
                
                Button {
                    coordinator.path.append(ContentViewRoute.SelectDepartureArrivalView)
                } label: {
                    Text("simulate selecting departure arrival with path")
                }

                Button {
                    coordinator.path.append(ContentViewRoute.ScheduleView)
                } label: {
                    Text("simulate navigating to the schedule view with path")
                }
                
                Text("NavigationLink").font(.largeTitle)
                NavigationLink {
                    SelectDepartureArrivalView()
                } label: {
                    Text("simulate selecting departure arrival with NavigationLink")
                }

                NavigationLink {
                    ScheduleView()
                } label: {
                    Text("simulate navigating to the schedule view with NavigationLink")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ContentViewRoute.self) { value in
                switch value {
                case .SelectDepartureArrivalView: SelectDepartureArrivalView()
                case .ScheduleView: ScheduleView()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear { print("\(type(of: self)) appear ")}
        .onDisappear { print("\(type(of: self)) disappear") }
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing viewmodel as stateobject. Try to make it optional and instantiate within onAppear